# How do I create a Dockerfile that allows me to create two different containers depending on a command line parameter?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project with a current version, let's call it A, and a future version, which we'll call B.

Both go services reside in the same project under `.../cmd/A` and `.../cmd/B`.

What I'd like to do is create a docker container for A and another one for B.

I can see [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage) that I can add a `FROM ...` for each in the `Dockerfile` but how do I use the docker-composer to generate two separate containers? Ideally, this would be a command line flag or two different docker-composer files. (Or maybe I can have two different `Dockerfile`s too?)

Comment: You can have two different Dockerfiles and build twice, once for each container with its corresponding Dockerfile.

Comment: @BurakSerdar How do I indicate which Dockerfile to use in the docker-composer?

Comment: There's a specific [`dockerfile:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile) option in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  You can also use the same image for both containers and override the `command:`.

Comment: @DavidMaze That makes the most sense. I used that technique and it worked. If you'd like to write an answer, I'll mark it as my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each separate container you declare in your `docker-compose.yml` file can have a separate [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) block.  That can declare a separate [`dockerfile:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile) for each image.  In the context of a Go package you'll probably need to always include the entire package in the upload, in particular including the `go.mod` file in the repository root.

So if your directory layout looks like:

```
myapp
+-- docker-compose.yml
+-- Dockerfile.A
+-- Dockerfile.B
+-- go.mod
+-- go.sum
\-- cmd
  +-- A
  | \-- main.go
  \-- B
    \-- main.go
```

Then you can point your `docker-compose.yml` file at both Dockerfiles:

```
version: '3'
services:
  version-a:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.A
  version-b:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.B
```

If you have a single `Dockerfile` that builds and installs both versions of the package, you can also override the [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) for each container, matching the Dockerfile `CMD` directive:

```
version: '3'
services:
  version-a:
    build: .
    command: A
  version-b:
    build: .
    command: B
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with docker entry points the same as it is done below

docker-compose

```
  rubygems-1:
    container_name: "ruby-container-1"
    image: My-image
    command:  service-b
  rubygems-2:
    container_name: "ruby-container-2"
    image: My-image
    command: service-a
```

docker file

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint

```
#!/bin/sh -e

case $1 in

  service-a)
    bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
  ;;

  service-b)
    bundle exec puma -C config/puma2.rb
  ;;

  *)
    exec "$@"
  ;;

esac

exit
```